# In iPhone devices, how can I download Video and photo both via a single click from web?

Tags: javascript, php, html, web

I have one web page, where I am displaying the live photos(Combination of photo and video). I would like to download both photo and video after clicking on the download button.

I got succeed to download it in Chrome and Mozilla browser of the desktop but it gets to fail in iPhone devices.

Please suggest.

Thank you in advance.

Here is my code:

```
<a href="#" id="downloadImage" data-photosrc="sample.jpg" data-videosrc="sample.mov">Download Image</a>

 <script>
$("#downloadImage").click(function () {

  var video = 'http://www.example.com/live-photo-web/sample.mov';
  var photo = 'http://www.example.com/live-photo-web/sample.jpg';

   downloadURI(video, "sample");
   downloadURI(photo, "sample"); 

})

function downloadURI(uri, name) {
  var link = document.createElement("a");
  link.download = name;
  link.href = uri;
  link.click();
  link.remove();
}
```

Comment: Do you have access to the server hosting the images? The proper way would be to send a header indicating that it is an attachment. You can also download it via Ajax and then convert it to a downloadable Blob file and provide it via JS. I think the latter way is not supported in every browser and it seems more complicated.

Comment: Yes, video and image are at my server. 

The challenging part is video and photos are downloadable in the web browser but not in iPhone.

Comment: You can easily solve it, if you specify the following header for all those files you want to be downloadable. This should work in every browser: `Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="filename.jpg"`

Comment: Using an apache server, you can usually define a `.htaccess` file and specify the required files to be downloadable. Otherwise you rely on the browser's default behavior (e.g. Chrome shows PDFs in the browser window, others provide a downloadable file).